# avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet), the frameFinished is 0 most of the time why?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I received a packet from rtsp by av_read_frame and decode it through

```
avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet)
```

After decoding i am checking  the value of frameFinished.

Most of the time i get the value of frameFinished is zero.  May be around
50% of the packet.

**Could you kindly hint me what could be the reason ?**

is this issue in any way related to 'I', 'P', 'B' packet types ?

Comment: Does the packet represent a whole frame or only part of a frame? Is this at the very start of a stream, before 1-2 keyframes have been read?

Comment: njahnke, i am not sure how to find if the packet is a complete frame, initially almost all the frames are unable to decode, after than drops down to 50% of frames.

Comment: Are you decoding frames at the expected rate (fps)? If yes then it is probably the case that packets do not represent whole frames but rather parts of frames.